# Flutter: turn off dark mode theme

Tags: flutter

When I test my app out with dark mode activated on my phone the cupertinoTabBar changes do a dark theme. How can I prevent this? I only want my app to be themed in light mode.

Comment: can you share your App Theme code?

Comment: Did you try setting the material app theme as a light one? Like this `theme: ThemeData.light(),`

Answer (score 12):

Set `ThemeMode.light` to `themeMode` field on your Top App Component Such as MaterialApp.

For Example.

```
MaterialApp(
   themeMode: ThemeMode.light,
)
```

In addition, there are 3 modes in the Flutter.

```
//Use either the light or dark theme based on what
//the user has selected in the system settings.
ThemeMode.system

// Always use the light mode regardless of system preference.
ThemeMode.light

//Always use the dark mode (if available) regardless of system preference.
ThemeMode.dark
```

Answer (score 1):

There's also a great thread on this here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/41067#issuecomment-571689955

I had trouble changing the color of the top bar. The solution is to add

```
<key>UIUserInterfaceStyle</key>
<string>Light</string>
<key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
<true/>
```

And add this to your `dart` code:

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
/// ...
SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(
      SystemUiOverlayStyle(statusBarBrightness: Brightness.light) // Or Brightness.dark
);
```

This will force your status bar to black instead of white.